# OpenCV can't find the right version of CUDA

Tags: python, c++, opencv, cuda, nvidia

I installed OpenCV 3.0.0 but I'm having troubles any C++ or Python code using OpenCV. For testing, I went into the directory `opencv-3.0.0/samples` and ran `cmake` to build the samples. I got the following error:

`CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
Could NOT find CUDA: Found unsuitable version "5.5", but required is exact version "7.0" (found /usr)`

However, I'm pretty sure that I have the CUDA 7.0 installed and I verified by getting the following output from `nvcc --version` on the command line:

`nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Feb_16_22:59:02_CST_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.0, V7.0.27`

Why might OpenCV think that I got the wrong version installed? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Are you sure you don't also have CUDA 5.5 installed?

Comment: I don't think so. In `/usr/local` I have a folder named `cuda-7.0` and another folder `cuda` which is a symlink to the folder `cuda-7.0`. CUDA 5.5 might have been installed somewhere else though. How can I check it?

Comment: It is telling you that there is CUDA 5.5 in `/usr`. All you can do is search for it

Comment: I searched for all cuda directories in `/usr` by `find /usr -type d -name "cuda*" ` but strangely, all I got was CUDA 7.0 files.

Comment: you could consider upgrading CMake to the latest version (currently 3.3.2)

Comment: I don't know why but upgrading to the CMake version 3.2.2 solved the problem.

Comment: Would someone care to add an answer?

Comment: I couldn't find the source of the problem although upgrading to CMake 3.2.2 solved the problem, that's why I'm not adding it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading from CMake 2.8 to CMake 3.2.2 seems to have solved this particular issue.

[This answer has been added from information gleaned from comments in order to get the question off the unanswered list]